# How to get Ajax form to work in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

net core and I'm building a to do list app to learn but iv hit a road block trying to add an item to a to do list with out refreshing the page.

With my current setup the controller method to add a todo item to DB and a script to get refresh the html on page are called on form submit but the html is updated before item is added to DB.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or what is the best way to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

My Div for Table:

```
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

My Input form:

```
<div id="addTodoForm">
    <form  asp-action="AddToDoForm" method="post" data-ajax="true" >
        <input asp-for="Item" class="form-control " placeholder="Add To Do Item.." />   
    </form>
</div>
```

My Script To update html (has a time out function as a temporary fix to this issue)

```
<script>
    $("#addTodoForm").submit(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/ToDos/BuildToDoTable',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#tableDiv').html(result);
                }
           
            })

        }, 500);             
    }) 
</script>
```

My method to add Item to DB:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddToDoForm([Bind("Id,Item")] ToDo toDo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string currentUserId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            IdentityUser currentUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
            toDo.User = currentUser;
            toDo.Status = false;
            _context.Add(toDo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return BuildToDoTable();
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the 'data' part in your ajax setup

Comment: Iv tried adding the data part in and calling my AddToDoForm Method in the ajax but it doesn't return anything when I do, maybe I'm not sending the right data does any one know how to or know a tutorial on the subject. Cheers

Comment: Hi @jacquesrockell, ajax is used to connect server and client without refreshing.Be sure the type of <input id="addTodoForm"/> is button instead of submit. Also, your backend action is named `AddToDoForm`, but your request url is `/ToDos/BuildToDoTable`. Be sure it is correct. I think you need share more code to us.

Comment: `<div id="addTodoForm">
    <form method="post">
        <input name="Item" class="form-control " placeholder="Add To Do Item.." />   
    </form>
</div>`

Comment: `<script>
        $("#addTodoForm").submit(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/ToDos/AddToDoForm',
                data: { Item: Item },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#tableDiv').html(result);
                }
               
            })           
        }) 
    </script>`

Comment: Hi @Rena I commented what I currently have for my form and script what im stuck is figuring out sending data to AddToDoForm()

Comment: Hi @jacquesrockell, remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in backend. If you do not want to remove it, you could use another way, you need send `RequestVerificationToken` header in ajax. Reference:https://forums.asp.net/t/2139422.aspx?Core+2+Ajax+submit+with+ValidateAntiForgeryToken+not+working

Comment: Iv added in the beforeSend function but AddToDoForm() still doesn't seem to be returning anything

Comment: I changed the id from div to form it didnt seem to help, im getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2) `

Comment: Hi @jacquesrockell, I've updated a whole working demo below. Please follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your whole code, here is a simple working demo about how to post data to backend and display the data from backend without refreshing:

View:

```
@model ToDo
<div >
    <form method="post" id="addTodoForm">
        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control "/>
        <input asp-for="Item" class="form-control " placeholder="Add To Do Item.." />

                  //focus here...it is type of button and add an onclick event here.....
        <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PostData()" />

    </form>
</div>
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
       function PostData() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#addTodoForm").serialize(),    //using this way to get the form data
                    url: '/Home/AddToDoForm',                    
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#tableDiv').html(result);
                    }
                })                
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddToDoForm([Bind("Id,Item")] ToDo toDo)
    {

        return PartialView("Partial", toDo);
    }
}
```

Partial.cshtml(jsut a easy view for testing):

```
@model ToDo
@Model.Item    //display the data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.preventDefault() which prevents the default behavior of submitting your form (refresh the page).

```
<script>
    $("#addTodoForm").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ToDos/BuildToDoTable',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#tableDiv').html(result);
            }
        
        });       
    }) 
</script>
```

Comment: The data-ajax="true" part in the form does the same thing as e.preventDefault() I think, but that's not the issue, the page doesn't refresh atm and the html is updated but I'm trying to get rid of the Timeout function because its a really bad fix to the problem.

Comment: BuildToDoTable() method is missing from your post. Your AJAX will POST to BuildToDoTable and not AddToDoForm.

Comment: The BuildToDoTable() just returns a partial view which is a list of the todos public`IActionResult BuildToDoTable()`
        `{`
            `return PartialView("_ToDoTable", GetUserTodos());`
        `}`

Comment: iv tried calling the AddToDoForm() but I'm cant seem to send data to it so it dosnt work, only way the method seems to work is if I have `asp-action="AddToDoForm"`

Comment: ```asp-action``` and ```url:``` inside ```$.ajax({})``` will do the exact same thing. ```asp-action``` will be generated to ```url``` just like ```data-ajax```. So it is conflicting now, I'm not sure which one it will pick up. Either AddToDoForm() or BuildToDoTable().

Comment: If I can do AddToDoForm() I think this could solve it but Im not sure how to get data to work as iv tried a couple solutions and they havnt worked. What am I suppose to put for data:

Comment: Please ensure jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX is installed. You may find more details about how to use it https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax

Comment: Yeah iv got it installed

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
    <script>
        $("#addTodoForm").submit(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/ToDos/BuildToDoTable',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#tableDiv').html(result);
                }
            });
            location.reload();
        }) 
    </script>
```

Comment: this dosnt seem to work and makes page refresh which im trying to avoid